# Override document on update

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am doing a findOneAndUpdate in mongoose:

```
Item.findOneAndUpdate({_id: 12345}, updateDoc, function (err, updatedItem) {
   //....
});
```

However I want to completely overwrite the document. According to mongoose docs:

> All top level keys which are not atomic operation names are treated as
>   set operations:

Is there anyway that I can override that behavior such that mongoose does not issue a $set operation for top level elements and instead overwrite the document?

Comment: delete the document and insert a new one :)

Comment: Why would I do that when mongo supports exactly what I want to do.  Mongoose does not.  For now I am accessing the native driver to perform a findAndModify, Item.collection.findAndModify(...)

Comment: @forumuser Can't you just create an `Item` and `.save()` it (cause you are querying over `id`)? Note that what you are doing might be unsafe, because it's against the idea behind Mongoose: to have a schema for Mongo.

Comment: @forumuser, I would recommend contributing the functionality you have made to the Mongoose library. I'm sure they'd love to see a pull request with that added functionality :)

Answer (score 9):

An "overwrite" option has recently been added. It replaces the entire document, the way Mongo updates by default. It's used like this:

```
Item.findOneAndUpdate({_id: 12345}, updateDoc, {overwrite: true}, function(err, updatedItem) {
....
});
```

I found some history on this feature in thier GitHub [Issues](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1081) area.

Comment: Nice find, @raym.  I tried it out and it works with `update` as well.

Comment: Helped me hugely! Thank you!